# How to find if value already exists in db with ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

good morning everybody!
I Have in my application a User class with a CPF property (In my country is equivalent to SSN - Social Security Number in USA), then I have my Identity already implemented and working. My question is, how do I find if already exists a CPF in db with UserManager?
Can I Use UserManager or should I use my DbContext?

I need to check if exists the same number that the user is sending on the API request, I've already set that the property index has to be unique.

```
    public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(AddUserDto addUserDto)
    {
        var user = _mapper.Map<User>(addUserDto);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, addUserDto.Password);

        if (addUserDto.Roles != null && result.Succeeded)
            await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, addUserDto.Roles);

        return result;
    }
```

Before the _userManager.CreateAsync(); I need to do the checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
var exist = await userManager.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.UserName == usuario.UserName);
if (exist)
{
    return BadRequest("Username Exist!!");
}
```

Comment: would be good if you could provide more explaination.